# Running php code inside an image file on a certain directory from nginx

Tags: php, nginx

We recently migrated to nginx and we need to transfer as well our htaccess config the like below from a certain directory/path(www.domain.com/images/test.jpg) in which that image file contains a php code that we want to run.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .jpg .png .gif
```

Did some research and found examples below, but since I am not really that familiar with how to configure nginx, I am not sure why it isn't working.

first:

```
location ~ \.(php|jpg)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

second:

```
location ~ .*\.php$ {
   root   /var/www/html/www.domain.com;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
       break;
    }
  include        fastcgi_params;
 #root           html;
 fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
 fastcgi_index  index.php;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/www.domain.com$fastcgi_script$
}
```

I hope some can help me.

**UPDATE 08/09/2019 -- ANSWER**

```
location ~ ^/pathname/images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
{
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting? is it 404 or the script is not running

Comment: You never specified what is wrong with the current config? You need to first detail what you are getting

Comment: @TarunLalwani I mentioned it didn't work as far as my knowledge? I don't know nginx and I've searched so much but found no answer, that's why I came here? I don't exactly know what's happening I'm represented by a normal broken image page but I am expected a PHP code to run and return me something but it didn't, that's what is currently showing

Comment: Can you do a `curl -v http://<someimageurl>` and run a url which you expect to work? And add log output to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani edited

Comment: What is the correct output of the image with the PHP in it supposed to be? Are you including PHP code in test.jpg that modifies the image itself, or metadata in the image? Also, what versions of PHP and NGINX are you using?

Comment: @ebcode nginx version 1.14.2, php version 7.0.33. The image file test.jpg has php code inside of it, that php code communicates to a server that returns something that will be process on a different file but this file will be returned within the image via include from php. This file returns just basically an image file as well but an actual image. Basically, we are controlling just what image to return via the php code and tricking the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this code:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    add_header        Cache-Control public;
    add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
    expires           7d;
}
```

You might need to modify `/index.php?$is_args$args` part on the try_files line so that you get the correct parameters for your script, as your initial question didn't show clearly what the parameters are you want.

Credits goes to [nginx serve image via php script](https://serverfault.com/questions/861727/nginx-serve-image-via-php-script)

Comment: I will try this one my friend, thank you for your answer

Comment: will this going to apply in all images in the domain? or how can we make it specific to a directory?

Comment: All images but the try_files will make sure that if the file already exists it gets served from the disk

Comment: @TarunLalwani how will the configuration will look like if I want to apply it only to the domain/directory_first/images/ ? all the images inside this directory can run as a normal php code?

Comment: @Roljhon any luck?

Comment: @RayA trying hard mate, but with no luck. I am not sure how to configure your setup above in nginx that will work on for a specific path.

Comment: For images, what should one replace this /index.php?$is_args$args with?

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to restrict to a domain and folder you can use the below approach

```
location ~ .*\.php|(/folder/images/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))$ {
   root   /var/www/html/www.domain.com;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
       break;
    }
  include        fastcgi_params;
 #root           html;
 fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
 fastcgi_index  index.php;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/www.domain.com$fastcgi_script$
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work still hmmm, what does the root stands for? should I replaced it with the actual path of where the web files are?  then the domain ? sorry, I don't really know nginx.

Comment: Are your Php files working? Can you also add your old apache config to question?

Comment: Yes, all working and I mentioned above that this is the only setup we had from apache before in htaccess `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .jpg .png .gif`

Comment: can you confirm if the image itself is a actual php file?

Comment: the image contains php code that runs when the image loads in the browser.

Comment: Are these files located inside `/var/www/html/www.domain.com/folder/images` only?

Comment: it's in /usr/share/nginx/html/folder/images